# Does every embedding between finite free $\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z$-modules split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Fix a prime $p$. For $n \geq m \geq 1$, suppose we have an embedding

$$\iota: (\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z)^m \hookrightarrow (\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z)^n.$$

Must $\iota$ split? That is, is there a finite free $\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z$-submodule $F$ of rank $n-m$ so that $(\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z)^n \cong \iota\big((\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z)^m\big) \oplus F$?

I didn't expect this to be the case, but I can't think of any counterexamples. References to ?? Smith-type-theory over artinian local rings or anything else useful most welcome; I just don't have a good way of thinking about these kinds of rings.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is injective as a module over itself--this is easy to prove by Baer's criterion.

Comment: @EricWofsey Perfect, thank you! Was searching around for rings so that free modules were injective, but forgot about Baer's criterion. Do you want to answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is injective as a module over itself.  More generally, for any $n\neq 0$, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is injective over itself.  To prove this, by Baer's criterion, it suffices to show that for any $d\mid n$, any homomorphism $f:d\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ extends to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  To prove this, just observe that $f(d)$ is annihilated by $n/d$ and thus must be a multiple of $d$.